# Two keys for one value javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there anyway to do something to assign a value for both keys while constructing the object?

```
{
"hello","bye": "alright" 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are plenty of clearer ways of doing that, including:

```
var val = "alright";
var obj = {
    hello: val,
    bye: val
};

// or

var obj = {};
obj.hello = obj.bye = "alright";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner that uses the lovely [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#object):

```
var obj = _.object(_.map(['hello', 'bye'], function(v) { return [v, 'alright']}))
```

`_.map` isn't needed on more modern browsers ([IE9+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Browser_compatibility)), so you can do:

```
var obj = _.object(['hello', 'bye'].map(function(v) { return [v, 'alright']}))
```

Either way, the resulting object will be:

```
{
    hello: "alright",
    bye: "alright"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiple keys for the same value using [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
var a = {"bye":"alright"};

function add_property(obj,prop1,prop2){
Object.defineProperty(obj, prop1, {
  get: function() { return this[prop2] }
});
}

add_property(a,"hello","bye");

console.log(a["hello"]); //prints "alright"
console.log(a["bye"]); //also prints "alright"
```